# Does lockForUpdates work for whereIn as well?

Tags: laravel

Can I use `lockForUpdates` to lock multiple rows at once?
The docs only provide example with `where` clause, but I need to use `whereIn`:

```
try {
DB::beginTransaction();

DB::table('table_1')
        ->whereIn('column', $values)
        ->lockForUpdate()
        ->get();

DB::table('table_2')->insert($values);

    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

Will it lock all the rows resulting from the `whereIn` clause?
Or it locks the entire table?

Or it depends on the SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `DB::listen` you can make sure of it. But you are right about it depending on what database management system you're using. I don't think Sqlite supports transactions with database locks for example.

Go into a tinker session with `php artisan tinker`

Run the command `DB::listen(fn($q) => dump($q->sql, $q->bindings))` so every query you make in that session gets outputted in the console as well.

Try doing your queries now. Here is what I got as a result.

```
> DB::listen(fn($q) => dump($q->sql, $q->bindings))
> DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [1, 2])->lockForUpdate()->get()
"select * from `users` where `id` in (?, ?) for update" // vendor\psy\psysh\src\ExecutionLoopClosure.php(53) : eval()'d code:1
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
[
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]
```

---

Another approach that doesn't need you to go into the console is to add the `DB::listen` line to the `register` method of your `AppServiceProvider` but instead of using `dump` you log the output. Now you can check your logs to make sure everything is working.

```
public function register()
{
    DB::listen(fn($q) => Log::debug([$q->sql, $q->bindings]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The `DB::listen` in this case is meant to check the actual query being executed, so in your example it shows `for update` which means it is supported? And if not it would show something else, like maybe without `for update` at all?

Comment: Update: In my case, the query result was: 
`"select * from 'table' with(rowlock, updlock, holdlock) where [value] in (?, ?, ?)"`. It means it's working right?

Comment: Yes, that is SQL Server's syntax for database locks. `for update` was MariaDB's